# Populate List with data from Binary Search Tree inOrder

Tags: java, list, binary-search-tree

I'm looking to store the values of a binary search tree in order in a List. 
I have a public method that calls the helper method, but when I print the list that's returned, i'm constantly getting an empty list...

```
public List inOrderList(){
    return inOrderList(overallRoot);   //root value
}

private List inOrderList(SearchTreeNode root){
    List<E> list1 = new ArrayList<E>();    //new list (will be returned)
    if(root==null){
        return list1;     //returns empty list
    }
     //List is NOT empty, let's do this thing.
    else {
        //create a new list, that calls left method recursive on left node
        List<E> podo = inOrderList(root.left);
        //Here, I *believe* we've reached the bottom. Add every podo to list1   
        list1.addAll(podo);

        //do the same thing for the right tree
        List<E> dopo = inOrderList(root.right);
        list1.addAll(dopo);        
   }

    //return the list we just filled from our BST
    return list1;
}
```

I elected not to try and fill my list with data alone. I figured using `addAll` and storing everything that way would be a better choice. Given that this solution was not working, I attempted storing data as well.

```
private List<Integer> inOrderList(IntTreeNode root){
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if(root==null){
        return list1;
    } else { 
        while(root!=null){
            List<Integer> podo = inOrderList(root.left);
            list1.add(root.data);
            List<Integer> dopo = inOrderList(root.right);
            list1.add(root.data);
        }
   
    }
    return list1;
}
```

I found that this at least filled the a list, however it simply inserted the root value twice and was done. I've been working on this for the last hour or so, and can't seem to come up with anything better, so I figured I'd turn to you guys.

Where am I going wrong/ how should I go about it?

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: Can you try passing the List1<Integer> object as the second parameter to your inOrderList method, Instead of creating a List at each recursive call? I am referring to your second solution.

Comment: What would adding a second parameter hope to do?

Comment: Nothing much, except that would further reduce the lines of code and help you focus/debug the part that is not working as intended.

Comment: I have always debugged with println's, allowing me to see where I am in the code. I'm not familiar with what you're referring to. I'll give it a shot and report back

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Perhaps eclipse. For instance here is a video tutorial on eclipse debugger. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drk_ldaRMaY

Answer (score 2):

In pseudo code your function would look something like this. I would recommend that you try the debugger and check how it works on a smaller input.

```
private void inOrder(Node node, List<Integer> list) {
  if (node == null) {
    return;
  }
  inOrder(node.left, list);
  list.add(node.data);
  inOrderList(node.right, list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was pretty much just approaching it the wrong way.

Solution:

```
public List<E> inOrderList() {
List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();
inOrderList(overallRoot, list);
return list;

}
//helper method
private void inOrderList(SearchTreeNode root, List<E> list) {
if(root == null)
    return;       
inOrderList(root.left, list);
list.add((E)root.data);
inOrderList(root.right, list);

}
```